# Array map as assets fields

Tags: javascript, arrays, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I'm using Hyperledger to define a model file.

I've got the following basic sample.

```
asset MyAsset identified by id {
  o String id
  --> MyOwner owner
  o String field1
  o String field2
}
```

My aim is to replace `field1` and `field2` (I've got many different fields, that may be customized at run-time), with a generic array map such as `String{} fields`, accessed on my script file as a key/value array.

How can I do that?

Answer (score -1):

you would define the asset like:

```
asset MyAsset identified by id {
  o String id
  --> Owner owner
  o String[] fields
  o Double balance
}
```

you would then access the array in your transaction (whatever you've modeled that as ...)

eg (sample)

```
transaction Trade {
--> Owner owner
--> MyAsset myasset
o Double amount
}
```

then access it in your asset like:

```
/**
 * Perform a deposit or withdrawal from a bank account
 * @param {org.acme.account.Transfer} txfr
 * @transaction
 */

function execTxfr(txfr) {   
// sample code below

if(txfr.myasset.fields == null) {
    txfr.myasset.fields = [];
}

// do some logic then push to array

txfr.myasset.balance += txfr.amount ;
txfr.myasset.fields.push(txfr); // just pushing the transfer transaction object to your array as an example

// update the asset registry with the new balance and trxn object added to fields

return getAssetRegistry('org.acme.account.MyAsset')
.then(function(registry) {
    return registry.update(txfr.myasset);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you Paul for your answer. I don't think it returns me what I need. I'd need to access something like `myasset.fields['field100']`, returning a `String` object, where `field100` is a field name defined at run-time.

Comment: So your question is really a javascript question (even though I answered in the context of Composer and modeling). I think you could easily achieve what you want using `indexOf` to find a String object by name and corresponding value (or  similarly, create it as key/value in the array on creation) -  so you could easily use it as a multi-dimensional array, as you control the logic and there won't be a limitless amount of 'fieldnames' in your array one assumes ? Hope this helps.